# this.standardizeDate[language] is not a function

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

```
export const LANGUAGES = {
    EN: 'en',
    TR: 'tr'
};

public standardizeDate: object = {
    [LANGUAGES.EN]: (date) => (this.convertDateToIsoFormat(date, '/')),
    [LANGUAGES.TR]: (date) => (this.convertDateToIsoFormat(date, '.')),
};

this.standardizeDate[language](this.dateToDisplay);
```

Sentry catch an error for this code. However, I can't reproduce it. I just find that it gives an Illegal return statement error while debugging. After researching and I wrapped the value with parentheses. I'm using Angular 6, Webpack as transpiler.

What is wrong with this code? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that the language variable holds the constant value of either LANGUAGES.EN or LANGUAGES.TR? Having any other values would give the "... is not a function" error

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Are using `this.standardizedDate` because you are inside a class?

Comment: Yes. I've solved this problem. The problem was not with this code. It was with this.standardizeDate[language] . I've set an initial value to language from the service.